# how do I overlap html <div> over another <div> correctly?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, ionic-framework

I am working on the UI of a details page. The page is getting its content from a data base which updates the content dynamically. So far the UI looks like the image that I have linked

[Current UI of details page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb4eD.png)

However when the content of div changes, it results in the images being covered too much.

The HTML is as follows.

```
<ion-content >
    <ion-title *ngIf="item">{{item.title}}</ion-title>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div *ngFor ="let image of image" >
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="12" offset="0">
            <img  id ="image" [src]="image" alt="this is the image"/>
          </ion-col>  
        </ion-row>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay">
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-back-button defaultHref="/tabs/tab4"></ion-back-button>
          </ion-buttons>
          <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
          <p>{{item.description}}</p></div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

The CSS is as follows

```
.container {
  display: grid;
 }

 .content, .overlay {
   grid-area: 1 / 1;
 }

 .content {
   margin-top: 20px;
 }

 .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius:  0px 0px 30px 30px; 
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;

 }
```

How can I dynamically update the content of the div without covering the image below it? Is there a way that I can push the image further down the page as the overlay gets larger due to more text?

Comment: Your `class="overlay"` div is absolutly positioned, so it won't affect the position of other DOM elements (i.e. push the image down) because its out of the flow of the document. Maybe an easy solution would be to give your `.overlay` a semi-transparent background - `background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);` instead of `#ffffff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using CSS grid you could do away with the absolute positioning on your `.overlay` class.

Make your `.container` class have this additional property `grid-template-rows: max-content minmax(0, 1fr);`

Then you can put your `.overlay` in the first row of the grid like you have, and then put your `.content` in the 2nd row so they stack.  On `.overlay` put `margin-bottom: "however much you want it to overlap`.  That will have them slightly overlapping while also pushing down the images as your content in the `.overlay` grows.  If you end up putting the `.overlay` before the `.content` in the source order, you will need to add `position: relative;` to `.overlay` to make it appear above the images.  So basically your 3 classes should look something kinda like this --

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: max-content minmax(0, 1fr);
 }

 .content {
   grid-row: 2 / 3;
 }

 .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  border-radius:  0px 0px 30px 30px; 
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
 }
```

You're essentially setting the two containers in their respective rows with no overlap and then using the negative margin to pull the images up slightly beneath the message.  Don't forget if you end up changing the HTML order and put the `.overlay` above the `.content` you will need to give it a `position: relative;` so it will display above the `.content`.  This creates a new stacking context for the overlay effectively always putting it above the pictures.  If you end up putting the `.overlay` above the `.content` in the source order you will have no need to use CSS grids though -- just so you know.